# Change element color based on linear-gradient background color html5

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a cool effect in html5 where a element in one side of the gradient has a diffrent color then the other side. Like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uzw5.png)

I tried using `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but it i dont know how to controll the colors on the diffrent sides of the gradient. Codepen: https://codepen.io/powerkuu/pen/eYRYJVb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `background: #ffff00;` to `background: #ecd54f;`. It fits a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the hex-decimal value of `background` property in `&:after` to `background: #ffff00;` Try to find a fine color adjustment from changing the hex value. (`#ffff00` is the value of pure yellow.)

[image: The Screenshot I have taken from your Codepen after I edited tour code.]

---

The Screenshot I have taken from your Codepen after I edited tour code. Wish you all the best.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to be able to change the exact color value on both sides  of the element to match the backgroud.